# jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery

i have datepicker on my form. and then i am adding datepickers dynamically to the form. and when i make choose to any of this datepickers. the value of datepicker is setting to first datepicker. how fix it?

Comment: Sounds like overlaping IDs but we probably need to see your code to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By making sure that each textbox you are dynamically adding has an unique id and name attributes and assigning the datepicker to its unique id.

Comment: i'm using .ascx to add new row to table. and every elements name are become from My model. no another way?

Comment: @AEMLoviji, nope, the datepicker is associated to the given textbox through its id and if you don't respect this it simply won't work.

Comment: @AEMLoviji you can still do it. I have a user control which includes a datepicker. You can use the control id of the user control as a prefix for the textboxID (ID="<%=this.ClientID%>_txt") and then include some JavaScript on the user control to initialise the datepicker ($("#<%=this.ClientID%>_txt").datepicker()).